# Using angular directives with prototype or object initializar approach

Tags: javascript, angularjs, oop

i'm trying to use angular directives with prototype or object initializer. Examples:

Prototype:

```
'use strict';
var Example = function Example($scope, $elem) {
  this.$scope = $scope;
  this.$elem  = $elem;

  this.init();
};

Example.prototype.init = function() {
  /// rest
};

var exampleDirective = function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'M',
        link: function($scope, $elem) {
            return new Example($scope, $elem);
        }
    };
};

angular
    .module('adminApp')
    .directive('exampleDirective', exampleDirective);
```

Object initializer:

```
'use strict';
var Example = {
  init: function($scope, $elem) {
    this.$scope = $scope;
    this.$elem  = $elem;


    // rest
  }
};

var exampleDirective = function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'M',
        link: function($scope, $elem) {
            return Example.init($scope, $elem);
        }
    };
};

angular
    .module('adminApp')
    .directive('exampleDirective', exampleDirective);
```

Both work, but i'm trying to figure out how should i use, if there is a convention for that.

I already search a lot about using angular directives like this and the most closer answer that i found is this: [Let's Make Full-Ass Angular Directives](http://joelhooks.com/blog/2014/02/11/lets-make-full-ass-angularjs-directives/)

I'm searching for a difference approach.

Thanks.

Comment: just fyi - typescript approach is similar to that - https://github.com/tastejs/todomvc/tree/gh-pages/examples/typescript-angular/js/controllers

Answer (score 0):

This is a service I made for pagination in the whole app... I think it could help you by providing a way you could use constructors in a directive as well... it isnt a full answer but maybe it helps.

```
'use strict';

/**
 * Paginator Service
 */

angular.module('paginatorService', [])
        .factory("paginatorService", function () {

            var ConstructorPaginator = function (scope, changeSearchParameter, type) {
                this._fillPaginatorScope(scope);
                this._setUpWatchOnPageChanged(scope, changeSearchParameter);
            };

            ConstructorPaginator.prototype._fillPaginatorScope = function (scope) {
                this._scope = scope;
                this._scope.maxSize = 4;
                this._scope.currentPage = 1;
                this._scope.currentPage = 1;
                this._scope.page = 1;
                this._scope.rowsPerPageOptions = [
                    {amount: 10, label: '10 rows per page'},
                    {amount: 25, label: '25 rows per page'},
                    {amount: 50, label: '50 rows per page'},
                    {amount: 75, label: '75 rows per page'}
                ];

                this._scope.rowsPerPage = this._scope.rowsPerPageOptions[1];

            };

            ConstructorPaginator.prototype._setUpWatchOnPageChanged = function (scope, changeSearchParameter) {
                scope.$watch('rowsPerPage', function (newValue, oldValue) {
                    scope.pageChanged(changeSearchParameter);
                });
            };

            return {
                ConstructorPaginator: ConstructorPaginator
            };

        });
```

Then I just call the constructor from a controller in this case

```
angular.module('')
        .controller('Ctrl', ['$scope', 'paginatorService', function ($scope, paginatorService) {

                new paginatorService.ConstructorPaginator($scope, account_id, false);
```

Comment: so, you don't think it is wrong using angular with prototype?

Comment: maybe I speak out of ignorance, but prototype should always make accessing faster... not that it matters sometimes but the only bad thing I see in it is having to type 'prototype' here and there... I did hear people say this

Comment: I agree, and i think weird way of angular naturally did.